# Trigger Process Builder when user receives lead, not queue

Tags: leads, queue, process, builder

I have many queues and do not want to reference every one of them by Id in my formula, particularly since I would need to update the formula every time I add a new queue.
I have a process builder workflow that I only want to trigger when a user receives a lead, and not to trigger when a queue receives a lead.  How can I do this?  It would seem that there's no way to tell whether it's a user that owns the lead or a queue without including every queue Id (or every user id) in the filters of the process builder or in a formula.

Comment: Set your PB to on insert/update for Lead.  In the criteria diamond check the Lead.OwnerId starts with 005.  005 is the Prefix for the User Object.  This will tell you when a Lead is assigned to a User, not a Queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Process Builder criteria diamond check the Lead OwnerId starts with 005

[image: Lead.OwnerId : Starts With : Id : 005]

This will tell you whenever a Lead is assigned to a User instead of a Queue

Comment: or -- formula field on Lead `IsOwnerAQueue` -- leads to better self-documenting process builder and workflow conditions